# Regex optional group text between parentheses but exclude parentheses in result

Tags: regex

For an application which at some point interprets a data definition text, I want to use regex. The regular expression should split the data definition into 4 groups for each line.

The problem is, there is a group between parentheses but it's also optional AND it should exclude the parentheses from the result. I've been trying some things but can't quite get it to work.

This is what I've got so far

```
\[(.*?)\]\s.*(varchar|datetime|int|numeric)(\(.*?\))?(.*)

# explanation
\[(.*?)\]                       # field name between brackets
\s.*                            # one or more spaces
(varchar|datetime|int|numeric)  # data type keywords
(\(.*?\))?                      # length or mask, ?=optional
(.*)                            # anything after that are the hints
```

For example the input it this

```
[LastName] varchar(50) NULL
[BirthDate] datetime(dd-mm-yyyy) NOT NULL
[HBa] numeric NOT NULL
[email] varchar(50) NOT NULL
[Followup] int NULL
```

There is a match for each line, for example the results for `BirthDate` is like this:

```
# current                   # desired
group 1: BirthDate          group 1: BirthDate
group 2: datetime           group 2: datetime
group 3: (dd-mm-yyyy)       group 3: dd-mm-yyyy
group 4:  NOT NULL          group 4: NOT NULL
```

Ideally group 3 should exclude the parentheses and also group 4 should not include the spaces at the beginning. Any idea how to do this? See example here:
https://regex101.com/r/x60Ekg/1

Comment: Just replace the third capturing group with a non-capturing group and use a capturing group inside the parenthesis. I.e., `(?:\((.*?)\))?` instead of `(\(.*?\))?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\[(.*?)\]\s.*(varchar|datetime|int|numeric)(?:\((.*?)\))?\s*(.*)
```

should do the trick. The only adjustments I made were

1. adding a non capturing group and inverting the literal parenthesis and capturing group for the `(50)` match.
2. adding `\s*` to eat spaces between the `(50)` group and the rest of the line (`NOT NULL` group).

Comment: Thanks, just want to mention I had a similiar regex for `CountPrint int NULL` and at first didn't work because of the `int` in column name. The regex didn't explicitly check for spaces so I replaced `\s.*` with `\s+` then it works.